# Configuring .NET databases with VS Code on Linux

Tags: mysql, asp.net, linux, mono, visual-studio-code

I have downloaded and installed VS Code to begin playing around with .NET on Linux. I have successfuly installed mono and scaffolded a new MVC project using Yeoman. The scaffolding gave me a `config.json` like the following

```
{
    "AppSettings": {
        "SiteTitle": "Website"
    },
    "Data": {
        "DefaultConnection": {
            "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet5-Website-70631559-83ea-4436-8916-44a78906688e;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am unsure of how to go about configuring and setting up a database. On Windows the `update-database` command in Visual Studio ran the migrations and created a localdb.

I would like to use mysql if possible, but haven't been able to find any documentation on it (and there's no NuGet console in VS Code).

How is this done on Linux? If this is not yet supported, will it be in the future?

Comment: Possible solution, discussion on the issue on github. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2122